# Dwarf Fortress won't run on Macbook Air

Tags: dwarf-fortress, macos

I downloaded the newest version of Dwarf Fortress on my Macbook Air, and I followed all the directions.
But when I try to open the thing called 'DF', it says

> "dwarfort.exe" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: .exe file on Mac? Are you sure you've downloaded Mac version of the game?

Comment: The Mac Download indeed contains an .exe file named that way, for some reason.

Comment: This sounds more like a rights issue on Mac. Is there an equivalent to the 'Run as Administrator' from Windows?